# Does Myriad exist Unicode TFF format?

Tags: fonts, typography, pdf, typefaces

I am trying to display the non-breaking dash with itextpdf. However, it can't not display in normal myriad font. But I really want to use Myraid.

Therefore I need to find a version of Myraid that support unicode. Could anyone know about it? Thanks!

A existing example: We have arial font, but we also arial unicode MS for unicode display. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS

Answer (score 1):

Adobe ships PostScript-flavoured OpenType fonts for many years now and they are ALL Unicode-based. So that is not the problem unless you have a really really old version from the 1990s. Supporting specific characters is a different matter altogether though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all the Myraid fonts don't support. Go into the link -- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/index.htm, and show the list of unicode in designated font. It shows `U+2011`(no-breaking hyphen) is not supported.